# Javascript SlideUp with multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now, I can only have one filter active. If I try to click on the other filter, it cancels the first one. How can I make them both stay active?

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0x43v59b/2/

html:

```
<div class="header-box">
  <div class="header-click">
    <h5>Publish Year</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="no-display">
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header-box">
  <div class="header-click">
    <h5>Condition</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="no-display">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.header-click').on('click', function() {
    $parent_filter = $(this).closest('.header-box');
    $parent_filter.siblings().find('.no-display').slideUp();
    $parent_filter.find('.no-display').slideToggle(500, 'swing');
  });
</script>
```

css:

```
.header-click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
.header-box {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Try include jquery in your project then your code works, look here https://jsfiddle.net/0x43v59b/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get rid of this line:
`$parent_filter.siblings().find('.no-display').slideUp();`

Its checking all siblings with class '.no-display' and sliding them up

```
<script>
  $('.header-click').on('click', function() {
    $parent_filter = $(this).closest('.header-box');
    //$parent_filter.siblings().find('.no-display').slideUp();
    $parent_filter.find('.no-display').slideToggle(500, 'swing');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('.header-click').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.no-display').slideToggle(500,'swing');    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the updated jquery function:

```
$('.header-click').on('click', function() {
    $parent_filter = $(this).closest('.header-box');
    //$parent_filter.siblings().find('.no-display').slideUp();
    $parent_filter.find('.no-display').slideToggle(500, 'swing');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, works well for your condition:

```js
  $('.header-click').on('click', function() {
    $parent_filter = $(this).next('.no-display');
    if ($parent_filter.is(":hidden")) {
        $parent_filter.slideDown();
    } else {
        $parent_filter.slideUp();
    }
  });
```

```css
.header-click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
.header-box {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Year Filter -->
<div class="header-box">
  <div class="header-click">
    <h5>Publish Year</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="no-display">
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Condition Filter -->
<div class="header-box">
  <div class="header-click">
    <h5>Condition</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="no-display">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers look correct to me, Just one more way to achieve this.

```
$('.header-click').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next(".no-display").slideToggle(500, 'swing');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script i made, hope this is exaclty what you want.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click','.header-click',function(){

       $(this).next().slideToggle(500,'swing');

      });
    });
  </script>
```